# Hangman : Not repeating the Guessed Letter again

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

def random_Words():
    print("Lets play HANGMAN")
    option = input("Please Chose option \n [1] Animals.\n [2] Countries \n      [3] Flowers \n [4] Pakistan's Cities \n");
    i=0;
    x= "";
    if(option=='1'):
        path= "code/hangman/Words.Animals"

    if(option=='2'):
        path="code/hangman/Words.Countries"

    if(option=='3'):        
        path="code/hangman/Words.Flowers"

    if(option=='4'):
        path="code/hangman/Words.PakCities"

    return random.choice(open(path).readlines());

def HangmanGuess(RandomWord, GuessedWord, Chances):
    Letters_Guessed = []
    if(Chances > 0):
        i=0;
        GuessOption = input("Guess a Letter :");

       if(GuessOption == Letters_Guessed):
            print("Already Guessed")

        GuessOptionValid= False;
        for i in range(len(RandomWord)-1):
            if(RandomWord[i] == GuessOption):
                GuessedWord= GuessedWord[:i] + GuessOption + GuessedWord[i+1:];
                GuessOptionValid =True;

        print(RandomWord);
        print(GuessedWord);

        if(GuessOptionValid):
            HangmanGuess(RandomWord,GuessedWord, Chances);        
        else:
            HangmanGuess(RandomWord,GuessedWord, Chances-1);
    else:
        print('You have lost!!')


Chances = 5
RandomWord = random_Words()
GuessedWord = ''
i=0
for i in range(len(RandomWord)-1):
    GuessedWord+= '_'

def Hangman_Drawing(RandomWord,GuessedWord, Chances):
    x= HangmanGuess(RandomWord,GuessedWord, Chances);
    x = ''

    if(GuessedWord!= RandomWord[i]):
        if(Chances==4):
            print("----------");
            print("|       |   ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("-----------");


        if(Chances==3):
            print("----------");
            print("|       |   ");
            print("|       O   ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("-----------");


        if(Chances==2):
            print("----------");
            print("|       |   ");
            print("|       O   ");
            print("|       |   ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("-----------");


        if(Chances==1):
            print("----------");
            print("|       |   ");
            print("|       O   ");
            print("|       |   ");
            print("|      / \ ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("-----------");


        if(Chances==0):
            print("----------");
            print("|       |   ");
            print("|       O   ");
            print("|     --|--   ");
            print("|      / \ ");
            print("|          ");
            print("|          ");
            print("-----------");


print(Hangman_Drawing(RandomWord,GuessedWord, Chances));
```

Hello Guys,
Iam stuck at a problem, I want to put up a check which verifies that if any letter is been inputted when the letter is 'Guessed' it checks whether the letter was been inputted before therefore giving a printed message to alert the user if any found
My code is having the 'check' code but i don't know what is missing or why it is not working whereas the rest of the code is perfectly fine.
Sorry iam a non-engineer so if any information is missing please forgive
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but semicolons are not needed at the end of lines in Python. They're *allowed*, and let you combine multiple statements on a single line (though that's usually bad style), but they're never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code that will prevent you from dealing with repeated guesses of the same letter.

The most obvious one is the test you're doing to see if the user entry was already guessed:

```
if(GuessOption == Letters_Guessed):
```

By using `==`, you're requiring that `GuessOption` be equal to the `Letters_Guessed` list. Since it will be a string, that will never be true. I think you want to be using the `in` operator here. It tests if the object on the left is a member of the container on the right:

```
if GuessOption in Letters_Guessed:     # parentheses are not necessary in Python conditionals
```

But that's not enough to actually make it work. The local variable `Letters_Guessed` is initialized as an empty list, and never gets anything added to it, so any membership test on it will always be false. You need to add each guessed letter to the list somewhere.

The next issue is a bigger one. It has to do with how you're organizing the control flow of your code. Currently you're using recursion to move on to the next guess after figuring out if the last one was good or not. However, this causes problems with `Letters_Guessed`, since that's a local variable, which will be re-initialized in each recursive call. If you want to stick with recursion, you'll need to pass the `Letters_Guessed` list between function calls just like you're passing your other arguments. I don't really recommend that.

A better solution would be to replace the recursive structure of your code with loops. Particularly, `while` loops would make a lot of sense. You could have one `while` loop that deals with the consequences of each guess (e.g. reducing `Chances` on a wrong guess), and another nested loop that checks the input to make sure it's valid (e.g. not guessed already, and maybe checking additional things like being a letter and being only a single character).

Comment: Well i would prefer recursive function. Anyways thank you for your precious time.

Comment: btw i found the solution for this.